# Can I reuse a character to multiple characters in one scene with the link feature?

Tags: linked-data

[image]

I want to link each character to a scene several times, as shown in the image above, and give them different animations.
We also adopted a link function to flexibly respond to character design changes.

However, as shown in the GIF below, the most recently created armature proxy controls all characters. I want each character to have its own proxy armature.

[image]

Is there a solution for this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it's a limitation of Blender. And it will be fixed for 2.8 if I'm not mistaking.

EDIT: [and I'm not](https://blenderartists.org/t/animating-multiple-characters-using-the-same-link-crowd-animation/1124405).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/67200)

Comment: It isn't a critique. It isn't a request. It IS the answer. https://blenderartists.org/t/animating-multiple-characters-using-the-same-link-crowd-animation/1124405