# Can I reuse a character to multiple characters in one scene with the link feature in Blender 2.8?

Tags: armature, linked-data

[image]
What I want to do is look like the image above.

[In fact, I posted the same question about Blender 2.79](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124843/can-i-reuse-a-character-to-multiple-characters-in-one-scene-with-the-link-featur)

[In the meantime, i have heard static override of the 2.8 version.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=X_-cKpV6Reg&fbclid=IwAR2xjOOtgMKDJZW017TfAimUQaJntjt_3Kf0MKouWYGXHDVnCuvRyoJ2c2c)
Therefore, I thought the above operation would be possible.

But today I tried one collection multiple linking & make proxy in Blender 2.8 and it failed.

[image]

I tried to create a separate proxy for the linked objects, but all the objects are controlled by the last proxy I've created.

What did I miss?

---

Dan's method: failure

[image]
I tested Dan's method.
(Operation in the following order: link → make proxy → link → make proxy)
However, the result is that the last-generated proxy controls all linked objects.

Comment: I don't know much about this but does it change if you make a proxy on one copy first (before duplicating), then repeat (Link in another copy > make proxy)?

Comment: @Dan
I tested your suggestion and attached a GIF at the bottom of the text. Please confirm.

Comment: Hm, I had trouble with something similar a while ago. Will see if I can work out what I did.

Comment: I just had a look and turns out I didn't solve it, I had to create duplicate rigs that weren't linked... I think it's still a shortfall of Blender unfortunately (?) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80522/multiple-character-instances-with-blenrig-workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a limitation of Blender at the moment. You can't link in multiple copies of the same rig for independent animations.

The workaround is to create copies of the original blender file and link in the copies.

Comment: good. Using multiple copies can accomplish my purpose.  
However, this video demonstrates that multiple overrides work in Blender 2.8 by static override. Is the update missing?  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_-cKpV6Reg

Comment: Edit: Just watched that video and appear it is possible! Sorry that looks like it should work but haven't tried in the new version of Blender.

Comment: Update: Appears it didn't make it into 2.8... https://blenderartists.org/t/static-override-wont-make-it-to-blender-2-80/1130694

Comment: Ah, if I had been constantly monitoring blenderartists, I would have noticed this. But I did not know that the static overrid has been postponed since 2.81.

Anyway, for now, let's link the characters using multiple copies methods. I would like to quickly try Blender's new referencing system!